# python-gammu not working with sudo

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gammu

I'm trying to make run a SMS sending python script from PHP.

**SendSMS.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gammu

sm=gammu.StateMachine()
sm.ReadConfig()
sm.Init()

message={
        'SMSC':{'Location':1},
        'Text':'blah blah bllah',
        'Number':'xxxxxxxxx
}
sm.SendSMS(message)
```

when i run it from the terminal with "sudo" it doesnt work.But works fine *without*  "sudo"

the error:

> gammu.ERR_DEVICENOTEXIST: {'Text': u"Error opening device, it doesn't
>   exist.", 'Code': 4, 'Where': 'Init'}

I want to run the SMS script from a php script using shell_exec(). The problems are:

1. I cant run the SMS script with sudo
2. I cant run it through php without sudo

Please tell me how to fix this

Device-Raspberry pi 3

OS- Raspbian

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it doesn't find the configuration file, by default it's [searched in user home directory](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/config/index.html) which is different when executed through sudo.

You can [specify path to configuration file on command line](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/index.html#cmdoption-gammu-c) however it's better to not execute gammu as root and [configure the device to be accessible by user](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/config/index.html#option-Device).